# Trying to find at least one similarity between two tables in two different databases

Tags: php, mysql, database

what I am trying to do is look for at least one similarity between two databases. One database is called `criteria`. The other is called `Tenant`.

Inside the tables that are in `Criteria` there are 10 columns. Inside the tables that are in `Tenant` there are 10 columns.

If you are a tenant and want to find the properties that are sold from owners, we have to look if there is at least one similarities between the tenant and the owner.

If you are a tenant where the primary key is the username lets say john. Then in order for john to be match with owners that want to sell their house or property, john must have at least one similarity with the owners. If he does then we go into the owners database and display the properties for sell.

This is my php so far for what I am trying to do. It is not a lot 
I have one database called ad, which contains the properties sold by owners:
for example Database_name(Ad) -> table_name(the name of the user that registers)-> each user has its properties saved up inside that table.

another database is called Criteria: Here are the users preference of the people that might want to rent their property. 
Database_name(Criteria) -> table_name(the of the user that registers)->there are 10 columns that have the following name: username,first rent, occupation,age,tenantgender,income,history, address,smoker,pet.
My last database is called Tenant: here there are the same columns as the Criteria database. If there is a match between this tenant with any of the tables in Criteria it goes inside the ad database and shows that users property. Once everything has been showed it continues searching for other tables that has at least one similarity in order to show the properties.

```
  <?php
  $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "ad");
  $query = "SELECT * FROM $username where adtype = 'offer'"; 
  $result = mysqli_query($db, $query) or die(mysql_error());

  $criteria = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "Criteria");
  $querycriteria = "SELECT * FROM tenantcriteria WHERE username = '$username'";
  $resultcriteria = mysqli_query($criteria, $querycriteria) or die(mysql_error());

  $tenant = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "Tenant");
  $querytenant = "SELECT * FROM preference WHERE username = 'john'";
  $resulttenant = mysqli_query($tenant, $querytenant) or die(mysql_error());




$queryall = "SELECT t.*
                        FROM $criteria.tenantcriteria AS t
                        JOIN $tenant.preference AS p
                        ON 't.firstrent' = 'p.firstrent' OR 't.occupation' = 'p.occupation' OR 't.age' = 'p.age'
                            OR 't.gender' = 'p.gender' OR 't.income' = 'p.income' OR 't.history' = 'p.history'
                            OR 't.address' = 'p.address' OR 't.smoker' = 'p.smoker' OR 't.pet' = 'p.pet'
                        WHERE 'p.username' = '$username'";
  ?>
```

Basically my question is how would I compare 1 table(in one database) with multiple table(in another database) and find at least on similarity. If at least one similarity is found it stops and it shows all the property that is sold by that owner. I hope I am being clear.

Comment: You don't have to call `mysqli_connect` for each database. You can use the same connection for all of them, just use `databasename.tablename` when you want to refer to a table in a different database.

Comment: An example would be helpful. For example I have three database Ad, Criteria, and Tenant. How would I connect, and call each of them ?

Comment: Could you show some more details of the table structures, and what you're comparing. Show some sample table contents and the expected result.

Comment: `select * from Ad.table1 AS t1 join Criteria.table2 AS t2 ON t1.somecol = t2.anothercol`

Comment: Why are you using `$username` as a table name in the first query? Do you really have a separate table in the `Ad` database for each user?

Comment: Inside Criteria database: the table structure is as follow:
username,firstrent, occupation, age,gender, income,history, address, smoker, pet.
Inside Tenant Database: The table structure is as follow:
username,firstrent, occupation, age,gender, income,history, address, smoker, pet.
Therefore I want to compare first rent, occupation, age,gender, income,history, address, smoker, pet, between that tenant with all the owners. If there is a match it shows that persons property, and continues with the rest of owners to try and find a match to show more properties

Comment: Please update the question with all the details, it's hard to understand them in a comment.

Comment: Also, include the names of the tables not just the databases.

Comment: I just did if you could check.

Comment: `$criteria` and `$tenant` are `mysqli` connection objects, not strings that can be put into a SQL query. I keep telling you that you don't need to open multiple connections, you just put the database names into the SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will find all the owners that have at least one similarity with the given tenant, and then list all their properties. The first query gets all the owner names whose criteria are similar to the given tenants. Then it loops through those results to get all the properties from those tables in the `Ad` database.

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root");
$sql = "
    SELECT t.username
    FROM Criteria.tenantcriteria AS t
    JOIN Tenant.preference AS p
    ON t.firstrent = p.firstrent OR t.occupation = p.occupation OR t.age = p.age
        OR t.gender = p.gender OR t.income = p.income OR t.history = p.history
        OR t.address = p.address OR t.smoker = p.smoker OR t.pet = p.pet  
    WHERE p.username = ?";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $username);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $ownername);
while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
    $owner_sql = "SELECT prop_name FROM Ad.`t.$ownername` WHERE adtype = 'offer'";
    $owner_stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $owner_sql);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($owner_stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($owner_stmt, $prop_name);
    while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($owner_stmt)) {
        echo "$ownername $prop_name<br>\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: what does the t mean? more likely the t'.'

Comment: It's a table alias so you can write `t.firstrent` instead of `Criteria.tenantcriteria.firstrent`

Comment: but now how would I access the owners property?  some sort of array?

Comment: I've added another `JOIN` with a table in the `Ad` database that I assume lists all the properties.

Comment: I don't really follow you when you say there are multiple tables. Having a separate table for each owner is a horrible design, you should just put them all into one table, with a column that contains the owner name.

Comment: There's no easy way to join with all the tables in a database. You would have to generate dynamic SQL that gets all the table names from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`, and then loop through each of them performing a join with that table.

Comment: This is hard for me to explain since I am new in MySQL.

Comment: Could you write me how to connect to different databases? I still didn't get it.

Comment: You don't need to connect to different databases, that's what I'm trying to tell you. When you connect to a database, that becomes the default. But you can always specify some other database by putting the database name before the table name in the SQL, as I did in my answer.

Comment: How I have set the structure of the database is pretty simple.
I have one database Ad in which I have tables named after the owners username. In which I have all the properties of each owner. In Criteria, I have each owners criteria preference, and each owner can only have one criteria preference. In Tenant, I have the tenants preferences, in which each tenant can only have one preference. So then I want to compare the tenants preference with the owners if it has one similarity, I go to that owners ad database and display its properties.

Comment: Having separate tables for each owner is a horrible design, because you can't join on table names, you can only join on contents of columns.

Comment: SELECT command denied to user ''@'localhost' for table 'tenant criteria' this is what it is saying

Comment: Do you have different permissions on each database, so you need to connect with a different username? Your sample code uses the same username for all of them.

Comment: no it was just that i had to change mysqli_connect() to mysql_connect().
also you know for the ad database, the name of the tables are t.username.So now would I do ad.t.username AS a ON...

Comment: I've updated the answer to add `t.` before the username in the `Ad` table.

Comment: You can't use `mysql_connect()` if the rest of your code is using `mysqli`. The two APIs are totally unrelated.

Comment: it doesn't work. How can I see what $sql returns? why do you put "?" on "WHERE p.username = ?"? also what does prop_name stand for?

Comment: `?` is a placeholder, it gets filled in with `mysql_stmt_bind_param`. Look up documentation on prepared statements.

Comment: `prop_name` was my made up guess for the column in the owner table that contains the property name. Replace it with the actual column name. I assumed it would be obvious that I had to make this up, since you didn't describe that table in the question.

Comment: I made another question its more clear if you could look at it please.